# How to download a archive using django response?

Tags: python, django, archive, zip

I want to download the archive after i created. The code is bellow:

```
def downloadArchive(room, catalog):
test = RoomTest.objects.get(idRoom=room)
zip_name = room.name + "_" + token_urlsafe(5) + '.zip'
zip_path = 'media/zipFiles/' + zip_name

if test.OLD_Archive != '' and os.path.exists(test.OLD_Archive):  # remove old file.
    os.remove(test.OLD_Archive)

with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as zipObj:
    for student in catalog:
        zipObj.write('media/' + str(student.file),
                     student.studentFullName() + os.path.splitext('media/' + str(student.file))[1])

    test.OLD_Archive = zip_path
    test.save()

    response = HttpResponse(zipObj)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip-compressed'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + zip_name

    return response
```

Every time i try to download, got error "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged". I think the route is broken. Any ideas how can i check the response route?

Btw: if i download the archive manually (after archive), it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i used:

```
response = redirect('/' + zip_path)
return response
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does/ how it solves the problem?

Comment: @SimonCrane, this code makes redirect to the archive path. I'm not sure if it's ok, but it works for me.